# gcloud sql operations wait throws INTERNAL_ERROR after csv import

Tags: mysql, csv, import, gcloud

I am trying to import a CSV file into a Google CloudSQL(Mysql) instance using `gcloud`.

After running the `OPERATION_ID=$(gcloud sql import csv..)` command to import and then waiting on the operations id using

`gcloud sql operations wait --project "$GCP_PROJECT_ID" "${OPERATION_ID}" --timeout unlimited --verbosity debug`
,

I get the following error

```
..failed.
DEBUG: (gcloud.sql.operations.wait) [INTERNAL_ERROR]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Software/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 983, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/Users/user/Software/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 809, in Run
    resources = display.Displayer(command_instance, args, resources,
  File "/Users/user/Software/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/display.py", line 483, in Display
    self._printer.Print(self._resources)
  File "/Users/user/Software/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/resource/resource_printer_base.py", line 275, in Print
    for resource in resources:
  File "/Users/user/Software/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/sql/operations/wait.py", line 66, in Run
    operations.OperationsV1Beta4.WaitForOperation(
  File "/Users/user/Software/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/sql/operations.py", line 96, in WaitForOperation
    retryer.RetryOnResult(
  File "/Users/user/Software/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/retry.py", line 229, in RetryOnResult
    if not should_retry(result, state):
  File "/Users/user/Software/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/sql/operations.py", line 80, in ShouldRetryFunc
    raise result
googlecloudsdk.api_lib.sql.exceptions.OperationError: [INTERNAL_ERROR]
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.operations.wait) [INTERNAL_ERROR]
```

The data however gets loaded successfully into the table but only the wait operation fails with the above error. Can anyone provide any help here?

Have already tried reinstalling `gcloud`, updating `gcloud` and python versions but same result. Restarting the cloud instance did not give any other result.

```
➜ gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 315.0.0
bq 2.0.62
core 2020.10.16
gsutil 4.53

➜ echo $CLOUDSDK_PYTHON
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing won't work because `gcloud sql import csv..` doesn't return the operation id. What you should do is:

1- run the import operation

2- list the operations and get the running import with:

```
OPERATION_ID=$(gcloud sql operations list --instance INSTANCE_NAME --filter="TYPE=IMPORT AND STATUS=RUNNING" --format="value(NAME)")
```

3- use the waiting command:

```
gcloud sql operations wait --project "$GCP_PROJECT_ID" "${OPERATION_ID}" --timeout unlimited
```

For more info about filter and format flags, check this documentations:

[filter](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters)

[format](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats)